# On some devices, Javascript assigns new text nodes only after second selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling, addeventlistener

I wrote a simple website, which displays 1 of 150 Psalms at random with a random image from a small array of images. Once loaded user gets two choices, either read another Psalm at random (button "Any Psalm") or choose one themselves (select element). The function that loads a random Psalm works fine, but the select button, though works fine on local server and also on my laptop after pushing it to Github, but on my phone and iPad it works only if you select again, so say you're on Psalm 20, then you select Psalm 83 and then nothing happens, until you select again, say psalm 102, only then that it loads psalm 83, so you're always one step behind.

I suspect it may have nothing to do with the code, nonetheless, here's my function;

````
 const selectPsalm = () => {
    loadingImage();
    let psalms = randomPsalm(psalmsBulk)[1];
    let selectedPsalmIndex = document.getElementById("choose").value;
    let lastIndex = () => {
        if(psalms.indexOf(psalms[selectedPsalmIndex])<10) {
            return 2
        } else if(psalms.indexOf(psalms[selectedPsalmIndex])<100) {
            return 3
        } else return 4
    }
    strHeading = psalms[selectedPsalmIndex].slice(0, psalms[selectedPsalmIndex].indexOf(psalms.indexOf(psalms[selectedPsalmIndex]))+lastIndex());
    strScripture = psalms[selectedPsalmIndex].slice(psalms[selectedPsalmIndex].indexOf(psalms.indexOf(psalms[selectedPsalmIndex]))+lastIndex());
    document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = strHeading;           
    document.getElementById('psalm').innerHTML = strScripture;     
}```

and these are my event listeners:
````

```
  //document.getElementById("random").addEventListener('click', newRandomPsalm);
  //document.getElementById("choose").addEventListener('click', selectPsalm);

  $('document').ready(function(){
    $('#random').on('click', newRandomPsalm);
    $('#choose').on('click', selectPsalm)
  })
```

```
I commented out my original js event listeners and changed them for jQuery ones, because I am learning jQuery and wanted to see it in my code, but both sets of statements do exactly the same.

You can see it in action at:

https://psalms.live/

My question is; what is wrong and how to fix it?
```

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that `on('click')` is not always suitable for select dropdown element. The correct syntax is `on('change')`.